# Why is sexual reproduction so much more common than asexual (in macroscopic organisms)? Fundamentally, what makes it better?

Tags: reproduction

I'm experimenting with an evolutionary method of creating a neural network. I use an asexual approach, but I've seen others use sexual approaches.

So I'm interesting in learning what's better about sexual reproduction as apposed to asexual, and biology is probably the best way to approach that question. So, why is sexual reproduction so much more common than asexual (in macroscopic organisms)? Fundamentally, what makes it better?

I'm struggling to understand what the combination of two gene sets does that couldn't be achieved by mutations to a child of asexual reproduction.

Comment: I'm not so sure "more common" is true unless you are talking about particular types of life. There are many very successful organisms that reproduce primarily via asexual reproduction.

Comment: I edited to specify macroscopic

Answer (score -1):

Genetic diversity is needed to prevent everyone from dying of the same disease. This is the problem with monocultures. Higher organisms are more susceptible to disease and thus reproduce sexually.

Furthermore, basically all organisms exchange DNA so they are effectively sexual.